# how to get win xp admin password w/o changing it

Tags: windows-xp, permissions, passwords, administrator

I just wanted to ask if there's a way to get admin password or access to admin acc without changing password or using any 3rd party software like running from cd or usb?

Comment: Sure you can acces to admin without changing or using 3rd party software. use the correct password. ;-)

Comment: One might question your motives...

Comment: @blah, you said no 3rd party software from CD or USB.  Are you able to download anything?  XP is a lot more liberal with permissions than Vista/7.

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly sure that there is no way to get it without running some other software. The only two ways I know of are bruteforce, which is not really worth while if there is a reasonably complex password, and the other is rainbow tables.

Comment: If you're using rainbow tables you can also try Ophcrack. but since they said no 3rd party programs, you can assume there's no easy way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes of course there is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_%28security%29), but [none of it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing) is [legitimate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coercion).

It's fairly safe to assume that if you need the password you will have a legitimate way to get it.

Unless you're the admin and you've [forgotten it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27oh!).  ;-)

[image]

Comment: +1 I have a feeling someone in this question is clueless... and he's not the admin!

Comment: If he was the admin then he wouldnt be specifying no 3rd party tools, I forget the password all the time (lots of machines) and I use the Offline NT Registry editor, which you are able to simply boot and use to replace the current password.